# SELECT Highest value, or values if top value is shared

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query which returns the runner that has retired the most amount of times:

```
SELECT runnerName, COUNT(runner) Retired
FROM `lapInfo` A JOIN `runner` B
ON A.lapInfoRunnerNo = B.runnerNo
WHERE `lapInfoRetired`=1
GROUP BY runnerName
ORDER BY COUNT(lapInfoRunnerNo) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

At the moment, if 2 runners both retired 1 time and no other runners retire, I would like the query to return both of these runners as they have both retired the most amount of times. I have tried MAX() instead of LIMIT but it still only returns one value.

I am using MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can get the maximum retired count in a subquery and then compare it to get all runners with the maximum retired count

[`SQL Fiddle`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8be6d/2)

```
SELECT runnerName, runnerno 
from runner r
join lapinfo l
on r.runnerno = l.lapinfoRunnerNo
group by runnerName
having sum(lapinfoRetired=1) =(
  SELECT SUM(lapInfoRetired=1) as TotalRetired 
  FROM lapInfo
  GROUP BY lapInfoRunnerNo
  ORDER BY SUM(lapInfoRetired=1) desc
  LIMIT 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having the names as a comma separated list, you can do:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(runnerName), Retired
FROM (SELECT runnerName, COUNT(runner) as Retired
      FROM `lapInfo` A JOIN
           `runner` B
           ON A.lapInfoRunnerNo = B.runnerNo
      WHERE `lapInfoRetired`=1
      GROUP BY runnerName
     ) r
GROUP BY Retired
ORDER BY Retired DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

By the way, using table aliases is a good idea.  But it is better when they are abbreviations for the table name.  I would suggest `li` for `lapinfo` and `r` for `runner`.